# Google Chrome displays the wrong favicon that I've linked to in my html

Tags: html, google-chrome, favicon

I have an HTML file with the following markup in the head tag:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="myFavicon.ico" />
```

With that, I expect to see my "myFavicon.ico" icon display in Chrome's tab and bookmark bar, but instead it's showing Youtube's favicon (i have a link to youtube in my markup). This make's no sense to me. It works okay in Firefox. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Try renaming your favicon file to be favicon.ico and putting it in the root (/) directory.

Comment: That didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

yeah. put it in the root folder www/yoursite/favicon.ico
and

```
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" /> 
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
```

Answer (score 2):

A stubborn "old" favicon was sticking around in Chrome. After updating and continual refresh didn't work, I went to `www.example.com/favicon.ico`.
The browser downloaded the updated favicon, and now it shows up whenever I visit the page.

Answer (score 1):

It might be that your browser has cached it. That's happened to me a few times.

Answer (score 0):

First: rename favicon to favicon.ico.

Second: go to your site example.ext and add /favicon.ico to the end like example.ext/favicon.ico you should see a favicon.

Third: try reloading (or refresh) then CTRL Shift R then CTRL F5 (very top of keyboard) favicon should update.

This should make your computer work and the rest of the world will probably update in a few days.

If you still have trouble then I don't know. It may be a Chrome issue which may get fixed in the next update. You can also go to http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues and add an issue.

Comment: Opera had a long-standing issue where it would display the wrong favicon (mainly in History rather than on the browser tab).